# vim: Using conquegdb with lldb?

Tags: debugging, vim, lldb

I am using vim + conquegdb for several years now and I am happy with it, however now on mac I want to use lldb.
Is it possible to use conquegdb with lldb? I tried setting the exe path to lldb, but it wont launch lldb afterwards (probably some parameter mismatch).

I also found [vim-lldb](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/lldb/tree/master/utils/vim-lldb) however I can't for the life of me get this to work/launch a debugger (and I fail to find any real useful help, and :Lhelp doesnt get me anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

From a cursory glance at the sources, it looks like conquegdb works by sending gdb command line commands, and parsing their output.  That's not going to work with lldb, both the commands and their output are different.